# How would one say 'map' as in a map in a video game in French?

Tags: demande-de-mot

People will sometimes call a representation of a world in a video game a 'map' in English.

For example:

*"Do you guys wants to play on 'pl_pier' [the name of a specific place in some video game] next?"*

*"Of course, it's my favourite **map**!"*

How would one say that in French?

Comment: Please consult a dictionary and include what you found in your resources and where you got stuck.

Comment: @livresque In the Cambridge and Collins' online English-French dictionaries, there were only definitions about physical maps.

Comment: @MysticalUser That's precisely the piece of information you should include in your question in the first place. Explaining the specific meaning of map as it is used here and what *[pl_pier](https://tsarvar.com/fr/maps/team-fortress-2/pl_pier)* refers too would also help people not familiar with the subject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In French we simply translate it, a map is "une carte" (which sounds like "card" in English by the way.)
In video game you just have to use this word.

Good to know, French people often use Anglicisms (especially the young generation), and say "map" instead of "carte", when they are discussing video games in French.

Comment: Ou un [niveau de jeu](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niveau_(jeu_vid%C3%A9o)).

Comment: I can confirm at least that Nintendo online calls levels in Splatoon 2 "cartes".